# "Cannot find declaration to go" protos declaration in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, grpc

I am trying to use **gRPC** proto file to generate stub code for inter-service communication. Everything is okay and when I run `mvn clean install`, it installs everything and builds **successfully**.

But still now `protos files` are in **red** color and can’t go definition when I click to go to it’s definition. It says me *`Cannot find declaration to go`*. When build is successful then why it is not possible to find declaration in `IntelliJ IDEA`? 
I clean every `cached` on IDE and indexing is also `successful`. I also cleared `m2 cache`.

Is there anything to find this solution so that I can go to `proto class` definition?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Did you add the folder where the generated classes are as a "Generated source folder" ?

Comment: Yes I added them whenever I was generating java code from proto code.

Answer (score 1):

Your `IntelliJ IDEA`  needs to generate Project setup. So you need to execute the main `plugin` goal, which is `idea:idea`.
Use this command. It will helped me.

```
mvn -U idea:idea
```

Here
`-U` = Forces a check for missing releases and updated snapshots on remote repositories